# jquery.validate dateISO: Is this actually usable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been trying to use jquery.validate to validate a form with a date field in it. I can make it validate properly on blur: I add a validateonblur attribute to fields where I want to do that:

```
        $("input[validateonblur]").blur(function () {
            $(this.form).validate().element(this);
        });
```

But when I submit the form, the validation at that point only validates required fields. It doesn't care what kind of garbage is in the date field. It completely ignores the dateISO attribute, whether I do it as an attribute in the HTML...

```
<input name="DOB" id="DOB" type="text" required dateISO="true" class="blah" />
```

...or like so:

```
    $("#MyForm").validate( {
        rules: {
            DOB: {
                required: true,
                dateISO: true
            }
        } );
```

...or both.

Also, I've noticed that when I submit the form, it shows popup/tooltip things for errors, while when I call $(this.form).validate().element(this);, it indicates errors in a completely different way, by inserting labels in the HTML. But then again, their [dateISO documentation page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/dateISO-method) has an example that behaves completely differently to what I'm seeing: It does validate actual date values, and it does its errors in labels on form submit. Why?! They're not giving it any parameters I'm not. Why do they get different results?

The documentation is pretty skimpy. The documentation claims that a form is given a valid() method when you call validate() on it to set up validation, but at runtime it's undefined:

```
//  UPDATE: I had a very poor understanding of jquery when I wrote this. 
alert(MyForm['validate']); // 'undefined'
```

Is this library in a useable state, or am I wasting my time?

Comment: The popups are generated by your browser, which I assume is Chrome after your submit. Are your requirements all being loaded/called in order?

Comment: Why on earth are you adding an `onblur` event to your fields?  The jQuery Validate plugin already has validation `onfocusout` enabled by default.

Comment: @RobAdams - that explains a lot -- it's even more broken than I realized! You're right, I just removed all the jquery.validate stuff and it still gave me those popups. What are "requirements"? The .js files I'm including? I copied all that directly from a j.v example, altered paths to fit, and at least some of the j.v code does in fact work, so... Dunno.

Comment: @Sparky -- I added onblur because I wanted it to validate fields when they lose focus. It didn't do that until I added the onblur thing by hand. Should it have done that? Maybe so, but all I've got in front of me is what I've got in front of me.

Comment: jQuery, and your JS files. I could only get this to occur by not loading jQuery before I tried loading validate. Onblur should be validating by itself. The fact that you had to call it should lead you to your issue. What does your console look like?

Comment: [jQuery Validation will validate "on blur" (`onfocusout`) by default](http://jsfiddle.net/WgyW5/). HTML 5 Validation is also automatically disabled whenever the jQuery Validate plugin is in play since the plugin adds the `novalidate` attribute to the `form` tag.  Otherwise, your problem cannot be reproduced as you've described and the rest of your OP just seems to be a rant.

Comment: @RobAdams -- Nothing in the console.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Are you calling all of your scripts in at the bottom of your body? Do you have jquery above validate? Is the last thing you called the script block with validate?

Comment: @Sparky -- It reproduces infallibly here. Obviously I'm doing something different, but I'd rather spend today looking at other validation options than trial-and-erroring this one.

Comment: @RobAdams - Included in the head tag at the top of the file, in order: json2.js, jquery-1.10.2.js, jquery.validate.js, additional-methods.js, then two of my .js files. Then there's a script block. First thing in there is jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ debug: true, success: "valid" });, next is $("#MyForm").validate(), then $(document).ready(function(){...}); I copied that (except obv. json2.js and my own files) out of the example I linked, except that I'm using a different version of jquery.

Comment: So that's wrong. You need to put validate inside document ready. The example loads all the scripts at the bottom. This is a basic order of operations to ensure that the form is actually in the DOM.

Comment: @RobAdams - I just tried moving the script tags for the jquery.validate stuff to the very end of the file, after the form. It throws an exception in valid() on line 104, var validator = $(this[0].form).validate(); // this[0].form is undefined. I'm done with this thing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobAdams - Just put validate() in $(document).ready(). Same error. Again, I'm grateful for your help on this.

Comment: @EdPlunkett this is really simple selector stuff, it's a shame to walk away from this library just because you can't get it to work. $(this[0].form) is not what you want. $(this.form) is what you're looking for.

Comment: $(this[0].form) isn't my code! It's in jquery.validate.js, line 104, character 4.

Comment: Please do not post your answer within your question.  Please post your solution as an answer below.

Comment: @Sparky I don't think any normal person would call that a solution. But if you insist...

Comment: I agree that it's not really a good answer.  However, to conform to how this site is supposed to work, you post a question within the question and an answer below... please do not post answers or solutions within the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be to use [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html). I had it doing usable validation within five minutes of downloading it.

Some of the custom validation stuff has some limits (e.g. it's a weird hassle to generate error messages on the fly, for example (say, to refer to user-comprehensible field names, if you add a custom validator which compares the values of two fields (UPDATE: Simple -- you can do per-field custom error messages in the HTML, of course!))), but so far I really like it. It was trivial to write a custom validator that uses moment.js to validate arbitrary date formats, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:  `alert( MyForm['valid'] );`

What is that syntax?

Have you tried:  `alert( $('#MyForm').valid() );`

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/bscTU/

**Quote OP:**

> Is this library in a useable state, or am I wasting my time?

This is by far the most widely used validation plugin for jQuery.  Its developer is a member of the jQuery and jQuery UI development teams.  So despite any user or documentation issues, it's very solid.

Why are you adding an `onblur` event to your individual fields? The jQuery Validate plugin already has [`onfocusout` validation](http://validation.bassistance.de/validate/) enabled by default.  Demo showing `onfocusout` in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/WgyW5/

Comment: I tried calling .valid() both ways. It's not defined. I added onblur because nothing validated on blur until I did that. I copied the code from an answer on stackoverflow to somebody else who had the same problem. "That syntax" is one way of accessing a property on a JS object. After the page is loaded, in both IE and Chrome, any element with an ID attribute is defined in the DOM namespace as its ID. I have <form id="MyForm">...</form> in the HTML, and while messing with jquery.validate, I lazily relied on that feature instead of more safely calling getElementById() for everything.

Comment: Oh, my God, you have to put all the script stuff after the form.